# Applying multiple rules with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current .htaccess looks like this, and currently has the function of ensuring https-access:

```conf
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But, I want it to do more than that, as my current link-structure isn't really SEO-friendly. Basically, I want to make changes so that I can type in the URL on the left, and have the URL on the right loaded.

```
https://nexuscompendium/heroes/li-li/ --> https://nexuscompendium.com/hero.php?h=li-li
https://nexuscompendium/heroes/       --> https://nexuscompendium.com/heroes/
```

I've come up with the following that seems to work just fine... as long as the HTTPS-rule above isn't also active, as the other rules simply removes the "https://" again.

```conf
    RewriteRule heroes\/role\/([a-zA-Z]+)(\/?)$       herorole.php?r=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule heroes\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$           hero.php?h=$1         [L]
    RewriteRule battlegrounds\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$    battleground.php?b=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule rotations\/([0-9\-]+)(\/?)$           rotation.php?r=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule sales\/([0-9\-]+)(\/?)$               sale.php?s=$1         [L]
    RewriteRule predictions\/([0-9\-]+)(\/?)$         predictions.php?w=$1  [L]
    RewriteRule universes\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$        universe.php?u=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule subuniverses\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$     subuniverse.php?s=$1  [L]
    RewriteRule events\/seasonal\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$ seasonal.php?s=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule events\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/?)$        event.php?e=$1        [L]
    RewriteRule skins\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/?)$         skin.php?s=$1         [L]
    RewriteRule mounts\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/?)$        mount.php?m=$1        [L]
    RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]+)(\/?)$                     $1.php
```

Long story short: Can I combine the rules above - and, if so, how? If not, is there a way to ensure the HTTPS-redirect otherwise?

Thanks in advance ❤

**EDIT**: Thanks to the knowledge that .htaccess loops until no more rules can be completed (along with the slight addition of ^ in the last RewriteRule, I got it working, as follows:

```conf
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^heroes\/role\/([a-zA-Z]+)(\/?)$       herorole.php?r=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule ^heroes\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$           hero.php?h=$1         [L]
    RewriteRule ^battlegrounds\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$    battleground.php?b=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^rotations\/([0-9\-]+)(\/?)$           rotation.php?r=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule ^sales\/([0-9\-]+)(\/?)$               sale.php?s=$1         [L]
    RewriteRule ^predictions\/([0-9\-]+)(\/?)$         predictions.php?w=$1  [L]
    RewriteRule ^subuniverses\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$     subuniverse.php?s=$1  [L]
    RewriteRule ^universes\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$        universe.php?u=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule ^events\/seasonal\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$ seasonal.php?s=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule ^events\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/?)$        event.php?e=$1        [L]
    RewriteRule ^skins\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/?)$         skin.php?s=$1         [L]
    RewriteRule ^mounts\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/?)$        mount.php?m=$1        [L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)(\/?)$                    $1.php                
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is not really a question about rewriting rules, as far as I can tell. The rules above certainly do _not_ redirect a client from https to http protocol (which actually is not possible automatically). Two possible issues here: 1. you need to take care to place the redirection to https _above_ the other rules in that dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"), otherwise requests won't get redirected to https. 2. you have some application logic that redirects to http again (which also will cause browser warnings and questions).

Comment: You should be able to debug this when looking into your browsers development console, check the "network" tab in there. This is where you will see the actual redirections sent.

Comment: I tried adding the HTTPS-part first, and it works (also confirmed by the tool I used to test: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/). However, I can’t figure out what causes it to redirect “back” to http again?

Comment: Well, what redirections do you see when you debug it as suggested? And how did you make sure that you are not looking at cached results? Also it would be interesting to know what actually happens when you are redirected "back" to http. Simply because none of todays browsers will follow such a redirection...

Comment: The only debug I know of would be the link I supplied. I’m a rookie, hence why I’m asking, after all.Having the https-rule first nullifies all following because of the [R=301] which is understandable - if I remove that, and one of the listed rules are met, it meets the condition - but reverts back to http, completely disregarding the https-rule. What other tools could I use, without dropping a potentially errours .htaccess on the server?

Otherwise, I’d have to check out that in-browser way, but I had hoped for a better way.

Comment: As said before: it is not those rules that redirect requests back to http. So there is no sense in looking for "another tool". Also I do not understand what what you mean by "nullifies all following". Yes, _if_ that rules gets applied then the redirection is performed and no other rules do get applied. But that is fine. The browser will immediately send another request to the https URL with the same request path. This time the https rule does _not_ get applied, so the following rules _will_ get applied. That is the standard procedure, no way around that.

Comment: You write "The only debug I know of would be the link I supplied". Yet in my second comment above I actually told you another approach on how to debug this. Which apparently you ignore. Why is that? Also you fail to respond to the other point I hinted at: that (most likely) it is your application logic (php) that redirects back to http. Which has nothing to do with your rewriting rules. Also you fail to respond to my questions about how the browser actually reacts to those redirections. Why is that? Why do you ignore all those questions?

Comment: Ah, so the rules would *both* be applied, as it’s executed twice because of said redirect? That’s nice to hear, and hopefully answers the problem! I wasn’t aware it worked like that - but it makes perfect sense.  I did spot your suggestions, sorry for not adressing it directly. I have only tested it with the above-mentioned tool, before I wanted to try it “for real”, but - as your other comment states - that might be the solution. I’ll test it **properly** once I get back to it later on. ❤️

Comment: It worked! Thanks a ton! I'll edit in the working version - feel free to reply, so that I can choose it as the answer, in case you get a benefit from it ❤

Comment: Great to hear that things work for you. Don't worry for the credits, I stopped collecting :-) Also I did not really answer anything but just gave general hints. Nevertheless I would suggest to you that you start learning a few debugging skills, the absolut basics I mentioned. You _can not_ operate a web presence without having a bit of knowledge how things work...

Comment: You’re completely right. I got a fair bit of an eye-opener, but will definitely look for more. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose to offer another answer here. Not because yours is wrong, it is great that you figured out a working setup yourself!

However your implementation can be optimized quite a bit. Yes, what you implemented is perfectly possible, but the more rules get applied the more the http server get's slowed down (we are talking about regular expression matching here, that is *quite* an expensive operation). So it might be worth to condense this a bit:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

    RewriteRule ^/?heroes/role/([a-zA-Z]+)(/?)$       /herorole.php?r=$1 [END]
    RewriteRule ^/?events/seasonal/([a-zA-Z-]+)(/?)$ /seasonal.php?s=$1 [END]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(\w+)s/([\w-]+)(/?)$
    RewriteCond /%1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^ /%1.php?h=%2 [END]

    RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z]+)(/?)$                    /$1.php                
</IfModule>
```

Here some of the optimizations:

1. the pattern in the redirection to https is not required, since you do not use what it captures anyway. So use the most simple pattern there is: `^` which always matches, since every string has a beginning.
2. Using `^/?` at the start of a pattern in a rewriting rule makes it work in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") *or* i nthe real http server configuration. More on that further down.
3. most of the escape characters (`\`) are not required. Leaving them away makes the pattern much easier to read.
4. redirect to absolute path if possible, that can help to prevent confusion.
5. use `[END]` instead of `[L]` in most cases *if your http server is not too old* ... It terminates the *whole* rewriting process if that rule gets applied, while the older `[L]` flag only terminates *this run* of the rewriting process, so the process loops again. That wastes quite some time, since certainly in this situation no other rule will get applied. So you save one run for every request.
6. you can combine some of the rules to a more general one which again reduces the number of rules. This is especially true the more rules come together over time...
7. do you *really* need case insensivity (`[a-zA-Z]`)? You know the references you hand out, you control them. And no one types those by hand, right? Also you often can use `\w` instead of `[a-z]`, easier, though not exactly the same. As said: often, but it makes things easier to read again.
8. also decide if you really need the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`. It prevents an internal error when the rewriting module is *not* installed, sure. But what for? Usually the application won't work without anyway...

OK, there is certainly more that can be said here. But this might be enough now give you a starting point. So I will end with a few general remarks:

---

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Nice, that’s a ton of great pointers for optimization right there - and those are always great! It’s nice to get my knowledge expanded. Just a minor bit: I can’t seem to spot where the date-parts of (predictions|rotations|sales) would get caught in the condensed version? Is there a 0-9 missing somewhere, or am I misreading it?

Comment: Since you only hand on that second part of those URIs anyway I assumed you do not really care at the level of rewriting of that were a numerical of a character based parameter. That is why I used the `\w+` instead of precise matching patterns. The only reason to use separate matching patterns I can see is if you do _not_ want to rewrite if you expect a numerical parameter but get a character based parameter, why ever, but rely on the last fallback rule. If that is the case then leave the rules separate as you had them, sure.

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I see what you meant. I indeed did _not_ use `\w` as I claimed in the last comment, I forgot to replace that. Fix that. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I aimed to only catch expected/possible values for the different types, and ended up writing them all out, as the parameter-letter (.php?X=) is often different, which (sadly) makes the rules harder to generalize, I’m assuming.

Comment: Sure, if that is the case _and you cannot change that cause of raised complexity_ , then stay with your set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the knowledge from **arkascha** that .htaccess loops until no more rules can be completed (along with the slight addition of ^ in the last RewriteRule), I got it working, as follows:

```conf
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^heroes\/role\/([a-zA-Z]+)(\/?)$       herorole.php?r=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule ^heroes\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$           hero.php?h=$1         [L]
    RewriteRule ^battlegrounds\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$    battleground.php?b=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^rotations\/([0-9\-]+)(\/?)$           rotation.php?r=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule ^sales\/([0-9\-]+)(\/?)$               sale.php?s=$1         [L]
    RewriteRule ^predictions\/([0-9\-]+)(\/?)$         predictions.php?w=$1  [L]
    RewriteRule ^subuniverses\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$     subuniverse.php?s=$1  [L]
    RewriteRule ^universes\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$        universe.php?u=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule ^events\/seasonal\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(\/?)$ seasonal.php?s=$1     [L]
    RewriteRule ^events\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/?)$        event.php?e=$1        [L]
    RewriteRule ^skins\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/?)$         skin.php?s=$1         [L]
    RewriteRule ^mounts\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\/?)$        mount.php?m=$1        [L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)(\/?)$                    $1.php                
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That phrasing is not entirely right... ".htaccess" does not loop at all, that is a _configuration file_ . It is processed by the http server process (so that one loops) from top to bottom. If any rule gets applied and changes the request, then the process reiterates from the top. This is repeated until no changes occur to the request, that is not quite the same as "no more rules can be completed". Think of it as a little clerk doing his work: every form he is handed will get processed, If something has changed he ask for confirmation. He is only satisfied if the form comes back without changes

Comment: That’s a great analogy, actually.